# emu8086 calculation with input value, can't get my code to work

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to get this code to work, however I keep experiencing problems in the conversion, I tried a bunch of examples that were answers to similar questions, but none of them work, but from it I sort of patched my own version of the code, I think, however it still doesn't work.

```
org  100h

jmp calc
message db 0dh, 0ah, "Input width. $"                    
width dw 10,?, 10 dup('?')
w dw 0

 calc: 
    mov dx, offset message
    mov ah, 9                ;output message
    int 21h  

    mov dx, offset width
    mov ah, 0ah            ;read input for width
    int 21h
    mov dx, width 


    .next_digit1:
    mov cx, width[bx+2]
    inc bx
    sub cx, '0'
    mul w, 10               ;convert width string into a number
    add w, cx
    loop .next_digit1

    mov cx, w
    add cx, 100        ; do calculation
    mov w, cx  


    mov ah, 2         ;output the result
    int 21h
```

my biggest problem is that the string to number conversion isn't working, and the other conversion method I tried that was suggested to me here previously:

```
; Input:
; ESI = pointer to the string to convert
; Output:
; EAX = integer value
string_to_int:
  xor ebx,ebx    ; clear ebx
.next_digit:
  movzx eax,byte[esi]
  inc esi
  sub al,'0'    ; convert from ASCII to number
  imul ebx,10
  add ebx,eax   ; ebx = ebx*10 + eax
  loop .next_digit  ; while (--ecx)
  mov eax,ebx
  ret
```

does not seem to work, mainly because the line

movzx eax,byte[esi]

gives an illegal instructor error, and if i change it to just mov, then byte[esi] gives a wrong parameter error and undefined var error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`byte` is a keyword, but you need to use it in conjuction with `ptr`:

```
movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]  # clear EAX and load the byte into its lowest eight bits
```

Your emulator need not support `movzx`. Then, alternatively, you can do what `movzx` does in two steps:

```
xor eax,eax                # clear EAX
mov al, byte ptr [esi]     # load the byte into EAX's lowest eight bits
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been struggling with trying to make that work for ages, you actually explained it in a way that I understood it! I have a nother question if you could help. I fixed the code, however I'm using 2 instances, of the same thing, and the second one gets stuck in a loop forever, I'm updating the code in a second to show the problem.

Comment: Fine, it's great it helped. Feel free to accept my answer, thanks. However, please post another question and don't overwrite the original one. I'm going to revert it to its original state, no offense. That's the way Stack Overflow works.